# PHP Rewrite URLs Without .htaccess Or Any Server Configuration

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm creating a PHP script, so, I can't rely only on .htaccess file. Because, every server doesn't supports .htaccess. So, how can I rewrite urls without any server configurations.

Current URL

```
https://example.com/file.php?tag=blabla
```

Expected URL

```
https://example.com/file/blabla
```

Thanks...

Comment: You can't. Full stop. You need a feature that is beyond what php alone can offer.

Comment: @arkascha, How WP Does

Comment: What you _can_ do is use a single php script which acts as a router of your application (pretty much standard, actually). If you then address all resources via the `QUERY_STRING` in requests, you can simply go and evaluate that inside your script. That works. But it offers a different URL structure than what you suggested.

Comment: Wordpress (which is what you probably mean by WP) uses that rewriting strategy the http server it is operated under supports.

Comment: `https://example.com/file.php/blabla` could work, assuming the server has ACCEPTPATHINFO enabled (usually the case, on Apache.) If you wanted to name your script just `file` instead - then you would need additional server configuration again, to make `file` get parsed as PHP.